# Checking if $p$ tautologically implies $q$

Tags: logic

What is the difference between $p\Rightarrow q$ and $p\to q$? Is $p\to q$ a necessary and sufficient condition for checking $p\Rightarrow q$ is a tautology? Are there alternative approaches?

Comment: What is $\to$?  Is it supposed to be a logical deduction, like $p \vdash q$ ?

Comment: Twistedly related: http://www.ditext.com/carroll/tortoise.html.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, $\to$ is the *conditional* (i.e. the *connective* "if__ ,then __") while "tautologically imples" is denoted with $\vDash$.

The relation between the two is the following:

> $p \vDash q$ **iff** $p \to q$ is a *tautology*.